# intellij not able to step into generated java class

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, dynamic

At runtime I create a .java source file, invoke compiler and dump .class file. Load this class, create object instance and invoke a method.

Intellij fails to match stack to generated source or bytecode.
If I restart, it happily loads java and class from previous run and allows to step through in debugger.

Is there a way to have these available during original run.

Comment: Where the generated file is located? (Is it in the [project sources](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html#folder-categories)?) Can it be navigated to with "Navigate | Go to Class" action?

Comment: Location is src/main/generated-java marked as source dir. After 1st run is over it can be navigated to. During the run - no. I found I can use debug action + refresh. Kinda kludge

Comment: Please contact JetBrains support team at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new and record a short screencast illustrating the issue